# sql lite storage set up in my react native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

i am frustrated to set up this sql lite storage. i am doing it for weeks. used expo and change to normal react-native. still getting a problem.
[this is when i try to console.log the opendatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cqu0.png)

and when trying like "***db.transaction(tx=> console.log(tx))***" it returns tx, but when i try this code   ***db.transaction(tx => {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Users', [], (tx, results) => {console.log('here')}})***
nothing happens.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow step by step for example code given below, also share the some more for more reference:
**OPEN DATABASE:**

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
const db = SQLite.openDatabase(
{
 name: ‘exampleDB',
 location: 'default',
 },
 (success: any) => { console.log(success) },
 (error: any) => { console.log(error) }
);
```

**CREATE TABLE**

```
const CreateUserTable = () => {

db.transaction((tx: any) => {

tx.executeSql(

 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "

 + "user "

 + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR, username VARCHAR, display_name VARCHAR, last_login VARCHAR, role_id INTEGER);"

 )

  })

 };
```

**INSERT DATA**

```
const StoreUserDataToTable = async (data) => {

try {

   await db.transaction(async (tx) => {

   await tx.executeSql(

   "INSERT INTO user (id, email, username, display_name, last_login, role_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",

  [data.id, data.email, data.username, data.display_name, data.last_login, data.role_id]

  );

});

} catch (error) {

 console.log(" StoreUserDataToTable ==>> ", error);

  }

 }
```

**GET THE DATA:**

```
db.transaction(tx => {

tx.executeSql(

 "SELECT * FROM user",

 [],

 (tx, results) => {

 console.log(" results ==>> ", results);

    },

   );

 });
```

FOR MORE DETAILS YOU CAN CHECK THIS LINK : https://infinitbility.com/react-native-sqlite-storage-examples-of-query/#create-table-query